# Selenium Java Element Not Visible

Tags: java, selenium, wait

I have got error with visibility of element. I declare my webelement like this:

```
@FindBy(css=".xyz") private WebElement operatorSource;
```

I call this element using:

```
@Override
protected WebElement getOperatorSourceWebElement() {
    return operatorSource;
}
```

I try to get button with ".xyz" class:

```
<div class="sources">
        <c:forEach var="source" items="${operatorSources}">
            <button type="button" class= "xyz <c:if test="${source eq operatorSource}">active</c:if>" onclick="changeOperatorSource('${source}', this);">${source.description}</button>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
```

I try to call the selenium using:

```
public void chooseChanelSource() {

        waitActions.sleep(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        waitActions.waitUntilVisible(getSourceWebElement());
        ...
    }
```

But it gives me always the same result - the element is not visible error.

Any hints?

**EDIT:**
Website code from user perspective (there is no xyz class anymore):

```
<div class="center-content bg-grey">
<div class="operator-message">Some text</div>
<div class="row source-row">
    <span>Source:</span>
    <div class="sources">
        <button type="button" class="active" onclick="changeOperatorSource('PHONE', this);">Phone</button>
        <button type="button" class="" onclick="changeOperatorSource('EMAIL', this);">Email</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The first button is active by default. I would like to click the second one (the one with "EMAIL" label).

Comment: Open page in Chrome and try css selector `.xyz` in DevTool to see the first found element by the css selector is the button you wanted and is visible or not.  If it's not the button you wanted, use css selector supplied by @DebanjanB at below answer;  if it's visible, increase the wait timeout.

Comment: Well, unfortunately botk solutions changed nothing to me. Since it does not matter which button I click (there suppose to be 3 or more) I even tried 

@FindBy(css="button") private WebElement operatorSource;

It didn't help out either.

Comment: your given html code actually is source code of page from developer perspective. Please give the html code from user perspective.  In order to do that, you can use Browser's DevTool or  Browser's context menu:  'Inspect'.

Comment: I updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

The *Locator Strategy* you have adapted seems improper. You can use the following *Locator Strategy* :

```
@FindBy(css="div.sources button.xyz[type='button']") private WebElement operatorSource;
```

Additionally, you need to increase the `wait` time period by a bit for the *webelement* to render in the *HTML DOM*  as follows :

```
waitActions.sleep(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code snippet:

```
@FindBy(css="div.sources button[onclick*='EMAIL']") 
private WebElement operatorSourceEmail;

@FindBy(css="div.sources button[onclick*='PHONE']") 
private WebElement operatorSourcePhone;
```